# How to center divs on mobile in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I gived the .fejlec div this css code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .fejlec
  {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

But it doent align my divs center on mobile. I want to align center these divs:
- .fejlec_logo
- .fejlec_kereses
- .fejlec_kedvencek
- .fejlec_kosar

On the uploaded photo, you can see that how it looks now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsZIw.jpg

[image]

```
<div class="container fejlec">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 fejlec_logo">
                <a title="<?php echo html($site_config['logo_text']); ?>" class="navbar-brand logo clearfix" href="<?php echo $host; ?>">
                    <span class="logo_text_1"><?php echo html($site_config['logo_text']); ?></span><span class="logo_text_2"><?php echo html($site_config['logo_slogen']); ?></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 fejlec_kereses">
                <form role="search" name="header_search_form" id="header_search_form" method="post" onsubmit="search_k();return false;">
                    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group bc-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control header_search_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Termékek keresése..." name="country_id" id="country_id" onkeyup="autocomplet();" >
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="search_progress"></i>
                            <input type="hidden" name="search_date" id="search_date" value="" />
                            <button type="submit" class="header_search_button"><i class="fa fa-search header_search_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bc-menu list-group" id="country_list_id"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 fejlec_kedvencek">
                <a href="<?php echo $host; ?>/kedvenc-termekeim" class="fav_items_header_link" title="Kedvenc termékeim"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kedvenc termékeim</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 fejlec_kosar">
                <a href="<?php echo $host; ?>/ajanlatkeres" title="Kosár">
                    <span class="header_kosar_text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ajánlatkérés</span>
                    <span id="header_kosar_text"></span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try old fashioned `margin: 0 auto;`:

```
.fejlec
  {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: But it doesnt have fix width.

Comment: There are probably added some extra margin or padding somewhere in the code, let's find it using browser tools. I suppose this is not problem with centering .fejlec container.

Answer (score 0):

Just use class of bootstrap

text-center

moreover

you are using text-center alignment in the container itself so it won't work that way,

you have to provide **fejlec** class in the col divs like below

```
 <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 fejlec_kereses fejlec">
                <form role="search" name="header_search_form" id="header_search_form" method="post" onsubmit="search_k();return false;">
                    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group bc-wrapper">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control header_search_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Termékek keresése..." name="country_id" id="country_id" onkeyup="autocomplet();" >
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="search_progress"></i>
                            <input type="hidden" name="search_date" id="search_date" value="" />
                            <button type="submit" class="header_search_button"><i class="fa fa-search header_search_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bc-menu list-group" id="country_list_id"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
```